# TextBox TextChanged property in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone

I read this article about TextChanged property in Windows phone:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742880(v=vs.110).aspx

I want to know if there is a property for TextBox so that I get notified when user put focus to that TextBox and then get notified when user clicks something else on screen to make the TextBox lost focus?

Basically, I have a multiple lines TextBox, which accept 'Enter'.
So I want to get notified when User changes the Text after he leaves the Text Box (not get notified every key the user enters in the TextBox).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [GotFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus(v=vs.95).aspx) and [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus(v=vs.95).aspx) events on `TextBox` you looking for